# missing keyword in cte

Tags: sql, oracle

```
with RSFC(CK,PK,LVL,HIER) as (
  select EMPLOYEE_ID,MANAGER_ID,0 as LVL,EMPLOYEE_NAME as HIER from COMPANY where MANAGER_ID is null
  union all
  select EMPLOYEE_ID,MANAGER_ID,LVL+1,HIER || '/' || EMPLOYEE_NAME from RSFC R inner join COMPANY F on R.CK = F.MANAGER_ID
)
SEARCH BREATH first by CK set ORDR
select a.LVL,a.CK,a.PK,a.HIER,ORDR
from RSFC a order by ORDR
```

### error

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*ACTION:
Error at Line: 244 Column: 8
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `BREADTH` with a D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `D` in line `SEARCH BREATH first by CK set ORDR`.

It should be `SEARCH BREADTH first by CK set ORDR`.

Comment: The `D` part is right, clearly; but referring to RSFC here is OK, this is the [recursive subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2077142) pattern.

Comment: @AlexPoole, didn't have much idea about that. Anyways thanks for pointing that. Edited answer as per.